# How to avoid session login failure with ecryptfs

Tags: xfce, encryption, tty, ecryptfs, manjaro

After encrypting my /home directory with the migrate-home ecryptfs-utils script I can't log in to an XFCE session on my Manjaro system from the normal login screen. If I try to, the session is terminated immediately with these error messages:

```
~/.xsession-errors

Unable to create /home/$user/.dbus
Unable to create /home/$user/.dbus/session-bus
Can't create /home/$user/*
...

/etc/mdm/xsession: Cannot find Xclients
/etc/mdm/xsession: line 212 exec:xterm:not found
```

If I log in as the user on a tty, logout there without any action, and then log in to the graphical session, the session gets started successfully. I am not sure why this is, perhaps there is a mistake in my auto-mount setup. (I don't have the issue in a VM in which I tried everything first.)

Thanks for any suggestions!